# Is there an improved/ better version for words list than AFINN's and wordstrength

Tags: words, sentiment-analysis, scoring

Is there an improved/ better version of words list than AFINN's and wordstrength?
I am not getting good accuracy with the limited list. I am looking for more words with the sentiment score associated.

Answer (score 6):

I have just pushed an extended version of AFINN to the Python Github repository:

https://github.com/fnielsen/afinn/tree/master/afinn/data

It is called `AFINN-en-165.txt` and has 3382 words and phrases. There is also an emoticon list, but I doubt it will increase the performance much, - if any.

You might still find that it is not good enough. There are several other word lists, e.g., SentiWordNet and NRC Emotion Lexicon (please note the different licensing terms. NRC is non-commercial). Aggregating word lists might help.

Otherwise you could try machine learning. Richard Socher program http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html may be worth a try.

Comment: I checked both of them but it does not seem to have the sentiment score associated. Please help if I am missing something here. Thanks...!

Comment: Which ones are you looking at SentiWordNet and NRC Emotion Lexixon? In SentiWordNet I find 'PosScore' and 'NegScore'.

Comment: I wanted to merge AFINN-en-165.txt and SentiWordNet however the latter seem to have a different scoring pattern because of which I cannot merge and my results may not be correct and NRC Emotion scores are all binary and is little confusing for me. Please advise.

Comment: Let me know if there is a logic/technique so I can merge the first two lexicon

Comment: Is there a way to merge these?  @Finn

Comment: You just merge them in the same dictionary and apply an appropriate scaling and offset for each of the word lists.

Comment: I am little worried about the scaling and assigning the scores for the words in SentiWordNet as it may have an impact on the output. Moreover for most of the words, there is PosScore and NegScores available.  I am not sure what do you mean by offset here in this context. Please help me with few examples (assigning the scores for few words). I am sure it will help me proceed further. @Finn

Comment: Also, I tried to take the proportional scores but it did not look good though. For example: 0.5 Pos Score = 2.5 equiavalent in AFINN. @Finn

Comment: Well, the scaling is part of the science and I cannot give you any definite answer. I would initially try 4 * PosScore - 4 * NegScore for merging with AFINN, but this might not be the best.